# Extract two substrings from a string

Tags: c#

what is the best and optimise wayto extract substrings from a specified string.

my primary string is like

```
string str = "<ABCMSG><t>ACK</t><t>AAA0</t><t>BBBB1</t></ABCMSG>";
```

where the value `AAA0` and `BBBB1` are not contstant. it is dynamic value collected from somewhere.

i need to extract AAA0 and BBBB1 here.

please suggest me if any function or optimize way to do this.

thank you!

Comment: You haven't described anything about it's meant to recognise what the values are. Are they always four letters and a digit? What would you want to happen to input of "ABCDEFGHIJKL"?

Comment: What do you mean with *not constant* and *dynamic* ? Can `AAAA1` also be `XYZW1` or `A1` or `AAAA2` ?

Comment: ... or aAanannanannn1 and BbBbBbBbBbBb666?

Comment: the value string is like "<ABCMSG><t>ACK</t><t>AAA0</t><t>BBBB1</t></ABCMSG>" in a xml response...

i cant able to paste this in description.

Comment: If your data is in XML, I recommend you take a look at the [XmlDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kza7w4k.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = @"<ABCMSG><t>ACK</t><t>AAA0</t><t>BBBB1</t></ABCMSG>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"<t>(\w+)<\/t>");

Console.WriteLine(matches[1].Groups[1]);    // outputs "AAAA1"
Console.WriteLine(matches[2].Groups[1]);    // outputs "BBB2"
```

This assumes that your data are always inside a `<t></t>` tag, also you might want to do some error catching in case no matches are found.