# extract substrings from a strings

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

what is the best and optimise wayto extract substrings from a specified string.

my primary string is like

```
string str = "<ABCMSG><t>ACK</t><t>AAA0</t><t>BBB1</t></ABCMSG>";
```

where the value AAA0 and BBB1 dynamic value collected from somewhere.

i need to extract AAA0 and BBB1 here.

please suggest me if any function or optimize way to do this.

thank you!

Comment: There is no need to post something twice, you already asked it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641113/extract-two-substrings-from-a-string

Comment: Depends on the complexity. If you are looking at full XML or HTML, then a good XML or HTML parser would be good. If every string is as simple as the one you pointed out, then I'd have a look at Regular Expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way to do it with XmlDocument

```
void Main()
{
    string str = "<ABCMSG><t>ACK</t><t>AAA0</t><t>BBB1</t></ABCMSG>"; 
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(str);
    var t = doc.GetElementsByTagName("t");
    Console.WriteLine(t[1].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(t[2].InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by all means inefficient, but it does what you are asking. It makes some assumptions that the layout of the surrounding XML is invariant.

```
var foo = "<ABCMSG><t>ACK</t><t>AAA0</t><t>BBB1</t></ABCMSG>"; 
var ary = XDocument.Parse(foo).Root.Elements().ToArray();

// ary[1].Value -> AAA0
// ary[2].Value -> BBB1
```